# vb combo box selected item to open in individual form

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, combobox

Am actually new in vb and trying to learn it, i have a combo box of 13 collections and a button, i want whenever a user selects an option from the combo box and clicks the button, it should open in an individual form. but the problem is whenever the user clicks on an option, all the 13 forms will open.

please help
here is my code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ComboBox1.SelectedValue = "1"
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "2"
    Form3.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "3"
    Form4.Show()
    ComboBox1.SelectedValue = "4"
    Form3.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "5"
    Form5.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "6"
    Form6.Show()
    ComboBox1.SelectedValue = "7"
    Form7.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "8"
    Form8.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "9"
    Form9.Show()
    ComboBox1.SelectedValue = "10"
    Form9.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "11"
    Form10.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "12"
    Form11.Show()
    Me.Hide()
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "13"
    Form12.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code as written will, in turn, tell the combo box to select each item from 1 to 13 and then display a form, sometimes (but not always) hiding the current form in turn.  There are a variety of ways you could change this to do what you want to do.  You should certainly be inspecting `SelectedItem` instead of setting it.  You could have a `Select Case` or set of `If`-`Then` statements to process it, or you could set up the combo box datasource so that each item contains a reference to the form you want to show (at the cost of making instances of all of them, even ones you don't want to show)

Comment: i tried the select case and if then too but whenever i run the program, the button does not work

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint in the event handler and stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: Please how do i do that. am new in coding. help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon what you are trying to do,
And what the other members advised you already,
It sounds like you did not correctly format your if...then and/or your select...case  statements.

The code below should do what you are trying to do.
We use the SELECTINDEX property to find out which index element in the drop down is selected at present.

Additionally, The code below can be affected (affected so it does not work) by any code in the combobox/dropdown object's event procedures if you have any of them setup.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '
    Select Case Combobox1.SelectedIndex
        Case 1
            Form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 1, 4
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 3
            Form4.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 5
            Form5.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 6
            Form6.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 7
            Form7.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 8
            Form8.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 9, 10
            Form9.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 11
            Form10.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 12
            Form11.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case 13
            Form12.Show()
            Me.Hide()
    End Select
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks THis Code solved it but Now when you click on combo box option 3, form 3 opens instead of form4. same if u click on option 6, form 6 opens. any corrections?

Comment: Comboboxes start their index at 0 (zero) they do not start at one. Most people set the first option as a prompt to the user something like "Please select" So if your first option is not a prompt then try to adjust your number accordingly. If you don't fully understand, drop me a mail. Or better still add the code you use to populate your combobox or list each item of you combo box, especially including the FIRST (topmost) item. The form to be displayed (in my code) matches the forms in your sample code. I expect the mix up is with the first element (Option 0)?

Comment: Worked Perfect. Thanks you Good

Answer (score -1):

1. Combo box to open Form
2. Add & Name Combo Box SelectFormsEdit
3. Go to Property Sheet, Data Tab, Edit Row Source, SQL:

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((MsysObjects.Type)=-32768));
```

4. Event Tab, After Update, ... Code Builder:

```
Private Sub SelectFormsEdit_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.OpenForm SelectFormsEdit, , , , acFormEdit
End Sub
```

5. Save everything